# how to stop listview refreshing in viewpager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, refresh, adapter

I am newbie to android. I'm trying to implement `viewpager` with 2 tab with a `listview` inside.
The problem occurs when i `scroll.Listview` contains one `spinner` and three `textview` which will be generate using adapter. if i select item from the first spinner generated then i get values of it.but when i go down an select different spinner then spinner which i selected earlier gets selected to position 0.

Here's the code

```
public class Baggage_Home extends AppCompatActivity{

TabLayout tabs;
private ViewPager viewPager;
public static TextView extra_total;


 private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_business_center_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_room_service_black_24dp,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.baggage_meal);

    extra_total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.extra_total);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

 extra_total.setText("₹ "+String.valueOf(InternationalRoundTrip.total));
    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Extra Services");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



}


private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code_cnt.equals("IN") || !Flight_search_new.to_cty_code_cnt.equals("IN")) {
                if(Flight_search_new.valtype=="Internationaloneway"){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Baggage_Home.this,FlightBookingPage_Int.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Baggage_Home.this,RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BAGGAGE","abcd");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Baggage_Home.this,FlightBookingPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Baggage_display(), "Baggage");
    adapter.addFragment(new Meal_display(), "Meal");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**XML FOR BAGGAGE CLASS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Baggage"

            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meal"

            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>



</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="@color/btn_color"
    android:id="@+id/extra_total"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**BAGGAGE DISPLAY CLASS**

```
public class Baggage_display extends Fragment {


ArrayList<Baggage_details> bagdetails=new ArrayList<Baggage_details>();
Baggage_Adapter baggageAdapter;
ListView listView;
public static ArrayList<String> title_adult_bag_arr=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_adult_bag_arr_rtn=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_child_bag_arr=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_child_bag_arr_rtn=new ArrayList<String>();


LinearLayout lvs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View views = inflater.inflate(R.layout.baggage_display, container, false);

    listView=(ListView)views.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    bagdetails.clear();
    title_adult_bag_arr.clear();
    title_adult_bag_arr_rtn.clear();
    title_child_bag_arr.clear();
    title_child_bag_arr_rtn.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(Flight_search_new.adult); i++)
    {

        if(Flight_search_new.valtype.equals("Internationalround"))
        {
            if(InternationalRoundTrip.api.equals("galileo"))
            {
                if (InternationalRoundTrip.provider.equals("ACH"))
                {
                    bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Onward",  Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code +"-"+ Flight_search_new.to_cty_code,"Adult -"+(i+1),RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage));
                    baggageAdapter=new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(),bagdetails);


                    if(RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage_rtn != null) {
                        bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Return", Flight_search_new.to_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code, "Adult -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage_rtn));
                        baggageAdapter = new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                    }
                    System.out.println("WWWWW"+RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage.toString());
                    System.out.println("RRRRR"+RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage_rtn.toString());

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Onward",  Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code +"-"+ Flight_search_new.to_cty_code,"Adult -"+(i+1),RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlebag));
                baggageAdapter=new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(),bagdetails);

                if(RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlebag_return != null) {
                    bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Return", Flight_search_new.to_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code, "Adult -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlebag_return));
                    baggageAdapter = new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                }
            }

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not Int Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }



    if(Integer.parseInt(Flight_search_new.child) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(Flight_search_new.child); i++) {

            if (InternationalRoundTrip.api.equals("galileo")) {
                if (InternationalRoundTrip.provider.equals("ACH")) {
                    bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Onward", Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.to_cty_code, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_child_bag));
                    baggageAdapter = new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);


                    if (RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage_rtn != null) {
                        bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Return", Flight_search_new.to_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_chi_bag_rtn));
                        baggageAdapter = new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                    }
                    System.out.println("CCCCCC"+RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_child_bag.toString());
                    System.out.println("PPPPP"+RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_chi_bag_rtn.toString());

                } else {

                }
            } else {
                bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Onward",  Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code +"-"+ Flight_search_new.to_cty_code,"Child -"+(i+1),RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlebag));
                baggageAdapter=new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(),bagdetails);

                if(RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlebag_return!= null) {
                    bagdetails.add(new Baggage_details("Return", Flight_search_new.to_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlebag_return));
                    baggageAdapter = new Baggage_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                }

            }
        }
    }



    return views;

}


}
```

**MEAL DISPLAY CLASS**

```
public class Meal_display extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Meal_details> bagdetails=new ArrayList<Meal_details>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_adult_meal_arr=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_adult_meal_arr_rtn=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_child_meal_arr=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> title_child_meal_arr_rtn=new ArrayList<String>();
Meal_Adapter baggageAdapter;
ListView listView;



LinearLayout lvs;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View views = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_display, container, false);

    listView=(ListView)views.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    title_adult_meal_arr.clear();
    title_adult_meal_arr_rtn.clear();
    title_child_meal_arr.clear();
    title_child_meal_arr_rtn.clear();


    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(Flight_search_new.adult); i++)
    {

        if(Flight_search_new.valtype.equals("Internationalround"))
        {
            if(InternationalRoundTrip.api.equals("galileo"))
            {
                if (InternationalRoundTrip.provider.equals("ACH"))
                {
                    bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Onward",  Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code +"-"+ Flight_search_new.to_cty_code,"Adult -"+(i+1),RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_meal_onward));
                    baggageAdapter=new Meal_Adapter(getContext(),bagdetails);


                    if(RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_meal_rtn != null && !RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_meal_rtn.isEmpty())
                    {
                        bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Return", Flight_search_new.to_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code, "Adult -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_meal_rtn));
                        baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal.size(); k++) {
                    String src_des = Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal.get(k);
                    bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Onward", src_des, "Adult -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal));
                    baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                }

                if(RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal_return != null && !RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal_return.isEmpty())
                {

                    for (int k = 0; k < Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal_return.size(); k++) {
                        String src_des1 = Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal_return.get(k);
                        bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Return", src_des1, "Adult -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal_return));
                        baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not Int Round", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    if(Integer.parseInt(Flight_search_new.child) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(Flight_search_new.child); i++) {

            if (InternationalRoundTrip.api.equals("galileo")) {
                if (InternationalRoundTrip.provider.equals("ACH")) {
                    bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Onward", Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.to_cty_code, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_child_meal));
                    baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);


                    if (RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage_rtn != null && !RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_adl_baggage_rtn.isEmpty()) {
                        bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Return", Flight_search_new.to_cty_code + "-" + Flight_search_new.trm_cty_code, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.ach_child_meal_rtn));
                        baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                    }

                } else {

                }
            }
            else {
                for (int k = 0; k < Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal.size(); k++) {
                    String src_des = Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal.get(k);
                    bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Onward", src_des, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal));
                    baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                }

                if(RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal_return != null && !RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal_return.isEmpty())
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal_return.size(); k++) {
                        String src_des1 = Round_ViewFlight.final_sec_meal_return.get(k);
                        bagdetails.add(new Meal_details("Return", src_des1, "Child -" + (i + 1), RoundFlightBookingPage_Int.titlemeal_return));
                        baggageAdapter = new Meal_Adapter(getContext(), bagdetails);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }



    listView.setAdapter(baggageAdapter);


    return views;

}
```

}

**GETTER SETTER FOR MEALCLASS**

```
public class Meal_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
public static ArrayList<String> spinner_items=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<Meal_details> rowItems;
public static ArrayList<String> jeet_aar_meal=new ArrayList<String>();;

ArrayList<String> Bag_selected_amount= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Bag_selected__key= new ArrayList<String>();



Meal_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList rowItems) {

    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView sector,status;
    TextView title_count;
    Spinner spinner;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_adapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meal_status);
    holder.sector = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sector);
    holder.title_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_count);
    holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    try
    {
        final Meal_details row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        String status = String.valueOf(row_pos.getstatus());
        String title_count = String.valueOf(row_pos.gettitle_count());
        String sector=String.valueOf(row_pos.getsector_name());

        holder.status.setText(status);
        holder.sector.setText(sector);
        holder.title_count.setText(title_count);

        holder.spinner.setTag(title_count+status+sector);
        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(MealSelectedListener);

            spinner_items = row_pos.getbaggage_list();




        holder.spinner = spinnerDetails(convertView, R.id.spinner, String.valueOf(rowItems.get(position).getbaggage_list()));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("PASS_ADAP ERROR:", e.getMessage());
    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}

private Spinner spinnerDetails(View v, int resId, String text) {
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(resId);

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            spinner_items);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    return mySpinner;
}
```

}

**GETTER SETTER FOR BAGGAGE CLASS**

```
    public class Baggage_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
public static ArrayList<Baggage_details> rowItems;
public static ArrayList<String> spinner_items=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> jeet_aar_bag=new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> Bag_selected_amount= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Bag_selected__key= new ArrayList<String>();

Baggage_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList rowItems) {

    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView sector,status;
    TextView title_count;
    Spinner spinner;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.baggage_adapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bag_status);
    holder.sector = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sector);
    holder.title_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_count);
    holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    try
    {
        final Baggage_details row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

        String status = String.valueOf(row_pos.getstatus());
        String title_count = String.valueOf(row_pos.gettitle_count());
        String sector=String.valueOf(row_pos.getsector_name());

        holder.status.setText(status);
        holder.sector.setText(sector);
        holder.title_count.setText(title_count);
        holder.spinner.setTag(title_count+status+sector);
        holder.spinner.setSelected(true);
        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(BaggageSelectedListener);

            spinner_items = row_pos.getbaggage_list();



        holder.spinner = spinnerDetails(convertView, R.id.spinner, String.valueOf(rowItems.get(position).getbaggage_list()));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("PASS_ADAP ERROR:", e.getMessage());
    }
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}

private Spinner spinnerDetails(View v, int resId, String text) {
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(resId);

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            spinner_items);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

    return mySpinner;
}
```

}

Can anyone guide me where I'm going wrong.

I have used

> viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

> if i select item from the first spinner generated then i get values of
>   it.but when i go down an select different spinner then spinner which i
>   selected earlier gets selected to position 0.

Keep store spinner selected index in your Baggage_details DTO:

eg:-

1) Add a new field (eg- spinnerIndex = 0 )in your class Baggage_details with getter/setter.

2) Get selected index and set in spinner in getView() of your adapter

```
 holder.spinner.setSelection(row_pos.getSpinnerIndex());
```

3) Write this inside BaggageSelectedListener

```
row_pos.setSpinnerIndex(userSelectedIndexOfSpinner)
```

Comment: thank you for response @Deven. it wont work, can you show with sample code.

Comment: I have not any sample code that fit with your code, as you are saying your spinner selection is refreshing  when you scroll listview means you need to store your spinner selection in POJO/DTO (that you are not doing now) as i described.